# Sharepoint / Project 2013 clean installation

Tags: 2013, installation, project-server

I am new to MS Sharepoint and MS Project 2013 Server.  Please let me know if I am looking in the wrong place or what information is needed to best diagnose my current issue installing a standalone Project 2013 Server.

I started with a brand-new Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine, with all the Important Windows Updates.

I followed    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197667(v=office.15)    successfully to the last step 8.

When I ran the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, I got the error

> Configuration Failed One or more configuration settings failed. 
>   Completed configuration settings will not be rolled back.  Resolve the
>   problem and run this configuration wizard again.  The following
>   contains detailed information about the failure: Failed to create
>   sample data.
>
> An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.
>   Additional exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> To diagnose the problem, review the application event log and the
>   configuration log file located at : C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_9_11_2013_17_48_27_974_1573423007.log
>
> Click Finish to close the wizard.

I have done some research into the problem, but would appreciate some tips on how to proceed.

I've manually shared `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Analytics_ea3ebb06-c49a-41c9-afd1-1bc4c9aa5777` with Full Access for the user mentioned, and for Authenticated Users.

I tried the fix at http://www.myriadtech.com.au/blog/James/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=57 on another VM several weeks ago, and broke everything, thus necessitating the clean start.  I'm willing to try it again, but I will make a snapshot of the VM first.

Comment: Please share errors from file C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_9_11_2013_17_48_27_974_1573423007.log and inspect windows event log. Is service pack installed to windows server?

Comment: The windows event log error starts with "Failed to create sample data.
An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.ProvisionDefaultPWASite()
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.PsiService.CreateApplication(String name, Type serviceApplicationType, SPServiceProvisioningContext provisioningContext)
   at

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.  The error in the log file is "Resource retrieved id PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog is Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at {0}, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again."  There are similar errors with either {0} or the selfsame file it's being written to.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing a scripted installation from [AutoSPInstaller](https://autospinstaller.com/). This is the best way to install SharePoint 2013 / Project Server.

This way you don't have to manually do all the configuration and you will be following the best practices for the installation (Least privilege, separate service accounts for separate services, etc.)

Also if you plan to reinstall in a separate VM you can just use your script and get started in no time.